# Duplicate names with two corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of student names and courses they chose.

```
StudentName   CourseName Age
John          3           16
Dean          2           17
Lisa          1           18
King          3           19
Lisa          2           17
John          2           16
John          2           12
Lisa          1           15
```

1. For student with same name, I want to do a value_count for different courses
   e.g., John, course 3 (1), course 2(2)
2. Use the highest frequency as the course code
   e.g. John, Course 2 (2 has the highest frequency)
   Lisa Course 1 (1 has the highest frequency)

Is it possible to do it with Python pandas instead of using a for loop?

Expected Output is:

```
Student Name / Course Name
John 2
Dean 2
Lisa 1
King 3
```

(The tricky part is Lisa and John. Lisa and John both correspond with multiple course number, we select the most appeared course number in this case)

Comment: Please show your expected output in table format

Comment: Just added in the question

Comment: @KeFeng Can you post the `df.to_dict()` result?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `groupby` + `value_counts`

```
df.groupby('StudentName').CourseName.value_counts().sort_values().groupby(level=0).tail(1)
StudentName  CourseName
Dean         2             1
King         3             1
John         2             2
Lisa         1             2
Name: CourseName, dtype: int64
```

Or we do

```
df.groupby(['StudentName','CourseName']).size().sort_values().groupby(level=0).tail(1)
StudentName  CourseName
Dean         2             1
King         3             1
John         2             2
Lisa         1             2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: could you explain sort_values().groupby(level=0).tail

Answer (score 0):

We can use groupby and aggregate using mode.

```
dfgb = df.groupby(['StudentName'])['CourseName'].agg(pd.Series.mode).to_frame()

print(dfgb)

             CourseName
StudentName 
Dean         2
John         2
King         3
Lisa         1
```

Comment: Mode will return series , you may still need slice the first one

Comment: That's why I have chained .to_frame()  which returns a df and the expected output. Am I missing something?

Comment: try [1,2,2,1] with mode ~ :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not following you @YOBEN_S. I changed some sample data using CourseName values of only 1 and 2 and my solution still seems to be providing the correct answer. Can you please elaborate some more?